# Hibernate-Search and Lucene 3.5 SpellChecker

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search with Lucene 3.5 and trying to implement a "did you mean?" spellchecker search. I want to use the index as the dictionary. The issue I'm having is that  the documentation for indexDirectory does not match the current method signature and I can't find any details about how to implement from any other sources. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here's what I've deciphered from the method signature itself, but it just results in a lock exception.

```
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(FileUtils.toFile(new URL("file:lucene/indexes/")));

IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_35, new                StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_35));

IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, indexWriterConfig);
IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(indexWriter, false);

this.spellChecker = new SpellChecker(directory);
this.spellChecker.indexDictionary(new LuceneDictionary(indexReader, "favorite"), indexWriterConfig, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Order is important.

```
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(FileUtils.toFile(new URL("file:lucene/indexes/")));
this.spellChecker = new SpellChecker(directory);
IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(directory, true);
LuceneDictionary dictionary = new LuceneDictionary(indexReader, "field");
IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_35, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_35));
this.spellChecker.indexDictionary(dictionary, indexWriterConfig, true);
```

Comment: I take it the issue was with opening multiple IndexWriters at once?

Comment: Correct. Opening the reader first solved the issue since it was not obtaining a lock.